# How to update the value in Angular X-editable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I can't make it save the values. For some reason I didn't completely grasp the documentation of the onbeforesave. Here's what I've written but this option doesn't work.

**html**

```
<div class='title' editable-text='task.title' onbeforesave="updateTitle(task)">
        {{task.title}}
</div>
```

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('Todolist', ['ngResource', 'xeditable']);

  app.factory('Task', [
    '$resource', function($resource) {
      return $resource('/users/:user_id/tasks/:id', {user_id: '@user_id'}, {update: {method: 'PUT'}});
     }
   ]);

  app.controller('TasksCtrl', [
    '$scope', 'Task', function($scope, Task) {

    $scope.user = gon.current_user

    $scope.updateTitle = function(task) {
        id: task.id,
        Task.update(task);
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

the onbeforesave function is executed before the model has been updated, so the task object you are passing is the unchanged object.

You have two options.  You can pass $data, which is the value of the field you are updating, or you can change the attribute to 'onaftersave' (which is called after the model is updated), to make sure you get the updated data.